# Need Google Apps Script Plotting Data on Google Sheets with Lines and Data Markers

Tags: google-apps-script, plot, missing-data, linechart

I wish to plot a chart with the data as shown: [image]

The dates on the left will be the x axis and each column will be its own series as shown:

[image]

This was done by simply highlighting the cells and making a scatter plot.

Id like it to be like a line chart where each of the series are connected and various ranges for the series (so that the 3rd data column is not skewing the range). For example I would have a range of 0 to 50 on the left, but the right (yellow) series would have its own rang eon the right from 0 to 160.

Here is what I have tried:

```
function createEmbeddedLineChart(sheetPlot, intStartRow, intStartCol, intEndRow) {
  var chartDataRange = sheetPlot.getRange(intStartRow,intStartCol,intEndRow-intStartRow+1,4);

  var hAxisOptions = {
    slantedText: true,
    slantedTextAngle: 60,
    gridlines: {
      count: 12
    }
  };
  
  var lineChartBuilder = sheetPlot.Chart().newScatterChart();
  var chart = lineChartBuilder
    .addRange(chartDataRange)
    .setPosition(5, 8, 0, 0)
    .setTitle('Da Big Plot')
    .setNumHeaders(1)
    .setLegendPosition(Charts.Position.RIGHT)
    .setOption('hAxis', hAxisOptions)
    .setOption("useFirstColumnAsDomain", true)
    .build();
 
  sheetPlot.insertChart(chart);  
}
```

My problems with this are that it does not connect the lines unless the data columns are continuous.

Thank you in advance for any guidance you can give on this. I am not finding it too easily in the google documentation here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/charts

***EDIT 2/17/2021 22:29PM PST***
Here is an example of what I would like.
[image]
also note that the date column has hours, minutes, and seconds too. But they are just hidden; hence why they are not on the dates.
I would like:

*two (or more) vertical axis scales.

*dots at each data point
*a line connecting the points

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `Id like it to be like a line chart where each of the series are connected and various ranges for the series (so that the 3rd data column is not skewing the range). For example I would have a range of 0 to 50 on the left, but the right (yellow) series would have its own rang eon the right from 0 to 160.`. I apologize for this. Can you provide the sample output chart you expected as an image?

Comment: Hello Tanaike,I have added an image of what I would like at the end of my post. I hope this helps in describing what I would like.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to create a line graph with your criteria. You could always [create an Issue Tracker feature request](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/create-issue-ui#create_an_issue) about expanding [`Charts`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/charts) to include your desired results.